# select part in image and apply color in that area

Tags: android, image, image-processing

requirement : 
load image, select the part of image and apply colour in that selected area. 
(e.g) picture of house. select wall and apply colour in it.

I know about get pixel and change it colour.
the problem is i cannot get select area in image and cant get it coordinates correctly.

image 1 :
input image :
(e.g) room image
[image]

output image:

select part of image (e.g wall) and apply color in it
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far (where is your code)? What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't see any question here. No question -> no answer.  At least provide an example image. What do you mean by "select"? how is this done?

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to know... Do you expect someone to write you 3 pages of detailed instructions and sample code if you are not even willing to spend more than 2 minutes on your post?

Comment: @Svaberg. i loaded image, i created rectangle box in it and from rectangle i get coordinate point. from coordinate point , i  change color of pixel of image.